# I want the image to be properly responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container">
<div class="info col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 page-header">
    <h2>One Piece Manga</h2>
    <p>
        Released: 1997 Author(s): Oda Eiichiro  Artist(s): Oda Eiichiro 
    </p>
</div>
<div class="op">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <img src="img/volume80.png" id="image" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="story col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">
        <p><strong>Gol D. Roger was known as the Pirate King, the strongest and most infamous being to have sailed
            the Grand Line. The capture and death of Roger by the World Government brought a change throughout
            the world. His last words before his death revealed the location of the greatest treasure in the
            world, One Piece. It was this revelation that brought about the Grand Age of Pirates, men who dreamed
            of finding One Piece (which promises an unlimited amount of riches and fame), and quite possibly the 
            most coveted of titles for the person who found it, the title of the Pirate King.</p>
            <br/>
            <p>Enter Monkey D. Luffy, a 17-year-old boy who defies the standard definition of a pirate. Rather than
            the popular persona of a wicked, hardened, toothless pirate who ransacks villages for fun, Luffy’s
            reason for being a pirate is one of pure wonder; the thought of an exciting adventure and meeting new
            and intriguing people, along with finding One Piece. Following in the footsteps of his childhood hero,
            Luffy and his crew travel across the Grand Line, experiencing crazy adventures, unveiling dark mysteries
            and battling strong enemies, all in order to reach One Piece.   </strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.op{
     float: right;
     width: 300px;
     height: 400px;
     margin-top: 100px;
   }
```

I tried making it responsive but in small screen size it doesn't really look responsive. I am not able figure out proper spacing for the para and image.
[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXVjJy)

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what you want it to do -- scale the image based on window size? (if so try using `vh` and `vw` units for the image). Change layouts? (If so consider @media queries).

Comment: I want it be fully responsive for every screen size. Right now in the demo on the small screen it is not getting aligned properly

Comment: This is a design question then, not a coding question.

Comment: Ohhh Can you help me?

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: In small screen size the image should be in the middle with the text properly aligned with the image.

Answer (score 1):

You have a fixed height and width, this is very bad as it will always keep this size regardless of what size screen your class needs to just be:

```
.op {
 float: right; 
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Having a fixed height stops responsive from working you could also try width and height as 100%

```
.op {
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-top: 100px;
}
```

if you want the image aligned in small screens create a media query and set the display to block and have a margin left and right of auto

```
.op {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 100px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```